# how to change volume on multi sound card system without affecting which app "plays" where

Tags: linux, pulse-audio

On my work pc there are 2 soundcards + hdmi. I use cinnamon desktop, but I think it will be the same elsewhere. The problem is, that I see "device settings" for selected device only. And the moment I change the device, all apps will be reassigned to this soundcard. So this app/applet is unusable. Cli app `alsamixer` does not show hdmi.

So how to make some device "louder/quieter" without reassigning pulseaudio sink for that app?

(motivation: I'm working and am on some call for example, while kid want to play some serie/fairytale/..., so I can do that without leaving work pc / fiddling with other devices controls. However I don't want to kids channel to join our meeting, just because some app simplified its UI more than it should)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pavucontrol` is capable to do that. I thought that distribution-specific applet is doing the same, but `pavucontrol` allows much more.